# Best method of passing large array to PHP

Tags: php, json, url

I am trying to find the best method for passing a large array of IDs from one page to the next.

I've built a simple downloadable image site that allows users to select any number of images to download. Right now, when a user selects an image its ID is stored in a JSON string inside a cookie. The problem I've been having is finding the best way to pass the JSON to the review before downloading page.

Currently, I'm sending the JSON as a URL parameter but I'm not sure if this is the smartest solution since the number of IDs in the JSON could reach into the hundreds.

I've looked in PHP sessions but I don't really understand how can I enable the user ability to add/subtract from the variable once the page has been loaded.

```
$(function(){
$('.download_cart').click(function(){
    var urlArray = [];
    obj = JSON.parse(getCookie("downloads"));
        if(obj != null){
            if(obj.items.length !== 0){
                $.each( obj.items, function( i, value ) {
                    urlArray.push(obj.items[i].id);
                }); 
            }
        }                           
    window.location = cart_url+'?array='+urlArray;
})
});
```

Comment: You could use localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Try `POST`ing your data to the new PHP page:

```
var data = 'urlArray='+urlArray
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'new_php_page.php',
  data: data
});
```

Now you'll be able to get your variable at `$_POST['urlArray']` on your new page.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Cutie Mark Crusaders Web Developers! :D

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working, after the call returns successful, I redirect window.location = cart_url but The $_POST variable shows null?

Comment: That's because you're `POST`ing a value to a script, and then expecting it to be there when you run the script again by redirecting.  You should look into using a simple <form> element with a `POST` method; not everything needs to be done with AJAX. Alternatively, modify your PHP script so it does its processing and returns a value you then use on your existing page, instead of redirecting.

Comment: Currently, I'm sending the JSON as a URL parameter but I'm not sure if this is the smartest solution since the number of IDs in the JSON could reach into the hundreds. I was asking the question to see if there was a better way of passing the json to my PHP page.

Comment: Yes, I read that and agree. Like I said above, you should look into using a `<form>` with a POST action or have your PHP script return what you need after POSTing to it with your jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Assign urlArray to a hidden field then submit the form, it can parse large no of array to another page

Answer (score 0):

Consider to pass them in a set of ajax-requests, by 200 (for example, to not overflow input limit) IDs in each request.